# Adobe Edge Animate and d3.js: d3.scale.range([value]) not working properly in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, d3.js, cross-browser, transform, adobe-edge

I'm trying to create a bar chart using Adobe Edge Animate and d3.js.

I'm having some difficulties with how the different browsers displays the axes. Here is a link to a d3 chart only containing axes and no data (the code is in **d3example2_edgeActions.js**):

http://www.nyhetsgrafikk.no/demo/d3example2/d3example2.html

- Mozilla Firefox and Opera: everything works
- Chrome and Safari: ticks are stacked on top of each other to the left

I believe this has to do with d3.scale.range([value]) not working properly - all though it does set the range of the chart (when I change the range and run the code my chart is changed), the ticks are stacked on top of each other. Chrome is not returning any errors. Any ideas to how I can fix this?

Comment: Sounds like this is more to do with Adobe than D3 -- usually you wouldn't have that many problems with a chart like this. Have you tried doing it just in D3?

Comment: No I haven't, the company I'm working for uses Adobe Edge Animate to make all their interactives, so although it might be possible for me to not use it once in a while, I'd rather find a way to combine the two. Not a big fan of Edge Animate, but have to use it.

Comment: Have you tried just the Adobe SVG in those browsers to see if that works?

Comment: No, good point, Lars. Will do that tomorrow and see how it goes. Thanks

Comment: It looks like it is the `.range([values])` in my axes code that causes the problems. In Firefox and Safari it works, but in Chrome and Safari the ticks are showing but are all lying on top of each other to the left - is there any way to break down range or write it in a different way?

Comment: In my code above values is `[height,20]` as in `.range([height,20]);`

Comment: Could you post a small example that demonstrates the problem please, preferably in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Of course, here is an example where everything is fine in Firefox and Opera, but not Chrome and Safari (the code is in d3example_edgeActions.js):
http://www.nyhetsgrafikk.no/demo/d3example/d3example.html

Comment: Have you tried converting your numbers to actual numbers? `+d.value` instead of `d.value`.

Comment: In [this example](http://www.nyhetsgrafikk.no/demo/d3example2/d3example2.html): http://www.nyhetsgrafikk.no/demo/d3example2/d3example2.html I have removed the data, leaving only the axes.

Comment: Turns out the range wasn't the problem. By adding a webkit-transform to my ticks and axis text like this `.style("-webkit-transform", function(d){ return "translate(" + 0 + "px," + y(d) + "px)"; })` everything now works fine.

Comment: Great! Would you mind adding this as an answer for reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the range wasn't the problem. By adding a webkit-transform to my ticks and axis text everything now works fine

```
.style("-webkit-transform", function(d){ return "translate(" + 0 + "px," + y(d) + "px)"; });
```

Adding a **webkit-transform** also does the trick if you're trying to create a d3 pie chart with edge animate, and probably in all other cases where you're using **transform** in d3. You might also want to add a ms-transform:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp